# Cant get session working with ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, session

I have a simple file to set a session variable

```
<?php
   session_start();

   $_SESSION['my_name'] = "dave";

?>
```

and a simple file to see the stored variable

```
<?php
   session_start();

   echo $_SESSION['my_name'];
?>
```

if I call the file in the browser the session value is displayed correctly but if I make a ajax call using for example using http://requestmaker.com/ or https://www.hurl.it/ then the body response is blank. I can't see what is going wrong here its driving me nuts.

Any ideas

Cheers

Dave

Comment: Are you sure the 2 sites mentioned keep session cookies? Have you tried it with a jQuery call or anything else you would like?

Comment: You can't control / manage sessions from other sites via AJAX like that.

Comment: CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Ah I see, because the request from then coming from another domain eg  http://requestmaker.com/ the session variables were invalid, guess I should have considered that, my excuse is that it's 2am!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to watch `$_SESSION['user_name']` variable when you saved the  `$_SESSION['my_name'].` variable

Correct one of the identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Its inappropriate to use third party http-request sites and still expect the session variables to be valid since the request is then coming from a different domain to your server.